# Jquery DataTable Date Filter

Tags: jquery, datatables, date-range

I have a jquery datatable and it has date filter.My Code looks like this as mentioned in the below plunker link mentioned.Pasting my JS code for DatePickers

```
$(function() {
  var oTable=$('#datatable').DataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
      "sSearch": "Filter Data"
    },
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

  });

  $('#datepicker_from').click(function() {
    $("#datepicker_from").datepicker("show");
  });
  $('#datepicker_to').click(function() {
    $("#datepicker_to").datepicker("show");
  });


  $("#datepicker_from").datepicker({
    "onSelect": function(date) {
      minDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
      oTable.fnDraw();
    }
  }).keyup(function() {
    minDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
    oTable.fnDraw();
  });

  $("#datepicker_to").datepicker({
    "onSelect": function(date) {
      maxDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
      oTable.fnDraw();
    }
  }).keyup(function() {
    maxDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
    oTable.fnDraw();
  });

});

// Date range filter
minDateFilter = "";
maxDateFilter = "";

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if (typeof aData._date == 'undefined') {
      aData._date = new Date(aData[0]).getTime();
    }

    if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
);
    http://plnkr.co/edit/yTAmQRJHN1zVdzYJBKop?p=preview
```

From and To Date Range Filter seems to be working fine.But along with these
I may have one radio button (ie: This week and this month)
this week radio button will should give results between today date and last week and and same is the case with month radio button.
How should I solve this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add radio button after date_filter :

```
<p id="radio_date_filter">
   <input type="radio" name="filterTable" value="week" />This Week
   <input type="radio" name="filterTable"  value="month"/>This Month
</p>
```

Write script that filter datatable based on selection :

```
$("#radio_date_filter input:radio").click(function(){


    var currentDate = new Date();

    if($(this).val() == 'week'){

      var weekDate = new Date();
      var first = weekDate.getDate() - 7;
      var firstDayofWeek = new Date(weekDate.setDate(first));
      minDateFilter = firstDayofWeek.getTime();


    }else{

       var monthDate = new Date();
       var firstDayOfMonth = new Date(monthDate.setMonth(monthDate.getMonth() - 1));
       minDateFilter = firstDayOfMonth.getTime();

    }

    maxDateFilter = currentDate.getTime();
    oTable.fnDraw();
});
```

[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ztd5tNqM3ne7CAf7UDO9?p=preview)

Comment: Thank You :) But in the plunker If I select week checkbox right now it is showing suppose it is 27-05-2015 and above one week records but I want to fetch records between 21 - 27th and same is the same with month .Kindly assist

Comment: Hi Bhavin there seems to be a small issue currently date format in the above plunker is mm-dd-yy I want the date format to be dd-mm-yyyy If I have added dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' the search doesnt seem to work What must be done here Please assist?

Comment: @ravicandy : searching is working. do you mean filtering(by this month and week ) is not working?

Comment: No bhavin if I change the date field in datatable to dd/MM/yyyy then the search fails where exactly to modify?